# A Weapon or a Toy?

Tags: knowledge, visual, nonogram, paper-folding

<sub>*This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #5: On-and-onogrami](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7415/78877)*</sub>

---

Hello, fellow puzzlers!

Here's a nonogram I made for you.
But it's not just a nonogram. There is a hidden object in it! Can you find it?

> [image: Nonogram]

<sup>*Click for a larger version.*</sup>
<sup>*Colour-blind-friendly colour guide: Circle = Red, Square = Blue.*</sup>

I suggest you take a printout of this, or else copy the numbers onto a square-ruled paper and then solve.

I promise that your paper will not go to waste. It may look like gibberish, but if you look closer, you will see everything clearly, as in a crystal ball!

If you don't understand what to do with it, don't just throw it in the trash. I told you, your paper would not be wasted. You can use it to catch bugs at least! But it should not be your goal.

As a final note, keep in mind the orientation. If you don't see a meaningful object, you've probably chosen the wrong side.

<sup>If you are unable to take a hard copy, or just don't want to do that, you can solve the nonogram on [penpa+](https://tinyurl.com/2ctbybjj) .</sup>

<sup>A csv version of the nonogram:</sup>

```
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,1,1,,,,2,
,,,,,,,,,2,3,,,,,,1,,1,,,,,,,,,,,4,2,,,,1,,,2,2,
,,,,,,,,,2,2,,,,,,1,6,3,,,,,,,,,,,2,1,8,,2,2,,,2,2,
,,,,,,,,,2,2,,,,,1,2,2,2,,,2,1,,,,,,,2,2,2,,2,2,,1,2,2
,,,,,,,,,,2,2,,,,3,2,2,2,2,,,2,2,1,1,1,2,,,2,2,1,1,2,2,,1,2,2
,,,,,,,,,,1,2,1,3,2,2,2,2,5,2,,,2,2,2,2,2,2,,,1,2,3,2,2,2,,1,2,1,
,,,,,,,,3,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,5,1,3,,,1,1,1,1,1,1,,,4,5,1,3,2,3,3,1,3,1,
,,,,,1,6,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,2,1,1,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,3,4,4,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,1,1,1,2,3,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,3,1,3,1,1,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,2,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,2,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,2,2,2,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,2,2,2,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,2,2,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,2,2,2,2,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,2,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,2,2,2,2,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,2,2,2,2,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,2,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,2,2,2,2,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,2,2,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,2,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,2,1,3,5,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,1,1,3,2,6,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,3,1,1,3,4,1,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,1,1,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,3,6,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Hope you enjoy :)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

First the nonogram solves like this:

> [image]

Then

> we note the [paper-folding](/questions/tagged/paper-folding) tag and "On-and-onogrami" wordplay hinting at origami. The flavor text also mentions catching bugs and crystal ball. So we fold our paper into the ["cootie catcher" aka "fortune teller" origami](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PAZKv_PVcn0).

We see

> [image]
>  ORIGAMI on the outside! We must be on the right track.

Then we

> open it and see
>  [image]
>  WATER bOMb! Which is both a weapon and a toy (and also another origami)!

So we

> fold a [water bomb](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QC3I1SGRF5c) and get
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  a six sided die! One fine toy.

Comment: Quality way to answer, with the real-life working demo!

Comment: @Stiv haha thank you. I actually drove to the store to buy grid paper for this.

Comment: Fantastic commitment - if I could upvote you twice for effort, I would! :)

Comment: Yep, that's it! Well done! And as Stiv said, great commitment. Thank you. Checkmark will come :)

Comment: Fantastic puzzle *and* solution, @ACB!